# Slice move out in d3.js slice click

Tags: d3.js, d3pie.js

Hi all I am very new  with d3.js charts I am try to add some additional stuff in [3D Donut](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/9994181) . Please go tho this link [Basic Donut Chart](http://d3pie.org/website/examples/donut.html)  ,I want add segment click feature into  [3D Donut](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/9994181) . I try bellow code

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()              
                .outerRadius(ir+10);

            slices.selectAll("path").on("click",function(d){

             d3.select(this)
           .attr("stroke","white")
           .transition()
           .duration(1000)
           .attr("d", arc)             
           .attr("stroke-width",6);
            })
```

with [3D Donut](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/9994181)  but not working as expected . Please help me to achieve this . A working example code will be appreciated.

Thanx .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a bit annoying.  Since each slice is composed of multiple paths, I thought at first you could group them in a single `g` and then transition that on click to "bump out".  But it looks like the author of "3D Donut" relies on the drawing stack to "hide" pieces of the slices behind each other.  So, instead I had to assign a unique class to each piece so that I could find all the pieces that belong to a slice.  After that you can just transition them out along the midpoint of their angle:

```
  function clickHandler(d, i) {
      var self = d3.select(this),
        pieces = ['innerSlice', 'topSlice', 'outerSlice', 'percent'],
        c = self.attr("class").split(" ")[1];

      if (self.attr("transform")) {

        pieces.forEach(function(d) {
          slices.select("." + d + "." + c)
            .attr("transform", null);
        });

      } else {

        var a = (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2,
          x = (ir + 15) * Math.cos(a),
          y = (ir + 15) * Math.sin(a);

        pieces.forEach(function(d) {
          slices.select("." + d + "." + c)
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + [x, y] + ")");
        });

      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      width: 960px;
      height: 500px;
      position: relative;
    }
    path.slice {
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    polyline {
      opacity: .3;
      stroke: black;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      fill: none;
    }
    svg text.percent {
      fill: white;
      text-anchor: middle;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    ! function() {
      var Donut3D = {};

      function pieTop(d, rx, ry, ir) {
        if (d.endAngle - d.startAngle == 0) return "M 0 0";
        var sx = rx * Math.cos(d.startAngle),
          sy = ry * Math.sin(d.startAngle),
          ex = rx * Math.cos(d.endAngle),
          ey = ry * Math.sin(d.endAngle);

        var ret = [];
        ret.push("M", sx, sy, "A", rx, ry, "0", (d.endAngle - d.startAngle > Math.PI ? 1 : 0), "1", ex, ey, "L", ir * ex, ir * ey);
        ret.push("A", ir * rx, ir * ry, "0", (d.endAngle - d.startAngle > Math.PI ? 1 : 0), "0", ir * sx, ir * sy, "z");
        return ret.join(" ");
      }

      function pieOuter(d, rx, ry, h) {
        var startAngle = (d.startAngle > Math.PI ? Math.PI : d.startAngle);
        var endAngle = (d.endAngle > Math.PI ? Math.PI : d.endAngle);

        var sx = rx * Math.cos(startAngle),
          sy = ry * Math.sin(startAngle),
          ex = rx * Math.cos(endAngle),
          ey = ry * Math.sin(endAngle);

        var ret = [];
        ret.push("M", sx, h + sy, "A", rx, ry, "0 0 1", ex, h + ey, "L", ex, ey, "A", rx, ry, "0 0 0", sx, sy, "z");
        return ret.join(" ");
      }

      function pieInner(d, rx, ry, h, ir) {
        var startAngle = (d.startAngle < Math.PI ? Math.PI : d.startAngle);
        var endAngle = (d.endAngle < Math.PI ? Math.PI : d.endAngle);

        var sx = ir * rx * Math.cos(startAngle),
          sy = ir * ry * Math.sin(startAngle),
          ex = ir * rx * Math.cos(endAngle),
          ey = ir * ry * Math.sin(endAngle);

        var ret = [];
        ret.push("M", sx, sy, "A", ir * rx, ir * ry, "0 0 1", ex, ey, "L", ex, h + ey, "A", ir * rx, ir * ry, "0 0 0", sx, h + sy, "z");
        return ret.join(" ");
      }

      function getPercent(d) {
        return (d.endAngle - d.startAngle > 0.2 ?
          Math.round(1000 * (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (Math.PI * 2)) / 10 + '%' : '');
      }

      Donut3D.transition = function(id, data, rx, ry, h, ir) {
        function arcTweenInner(a) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
          this._current = i(0);
          return function(t) {
            return pieInner(i(t), rx + 0.5, ry + 0.5, h, ir);
          };
        }

        function arcTweenTop(a) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
          this._current = i(0);
          return function(t) {
            return pieTop(i(t), rx, ry, ir);
          };
        }

        function arcTweenOuter(a) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
          this._current = i(0);
          return function(t) {
            return pieOuter(i(t), rx - .5, ry - .5, h);
          };
        }

        function textTweenX(a) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
          this._current = i(0);
          return function(t) {
            return 0.6 * rx * Math.cos(0.5 * (i(t).startAngle + i(t).endAngle));
          };
        }

        function textTweenY(a) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
          this._current = i(0);
          return function(t) {
            return 0.6 * rx * Math.sin(0.5 * (i(t).startAngle + i(t).endAngle));
          };
        }

        var _data = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        })(data);

        d3.select("#" + id).selectAll(".innerSlice").data(_data)
          .transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTweenInner);

        d3.select("#" + id).selectAll(".topSlice").data(_data)
          .transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTweenTop);

        d3.select("#" + id).selectAll(".outerSlice").data(_data)
          .transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTweenOuter);

        d3.select("#" + id).selectAll(".percent").data(_data).transition().duration(750)
          .attrTween("x", textTweenX).attrTween("y", textTweenY).text(getPercent);
      }

      Donut3D.draw = function(id, data, x /*center x*/ , y /*center y*/ ,
        rx /*radius x*/ , ry /*radius y*/ , h /*height*/ , ir /*inner radius*/ ) {

        var _data = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
          return d.value;
        })(data);

        var slices = d3.select("#" + id).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")")
          .attr("class", "slices");

        slices.selectAll(".innerSlice").data(_data).enter().append("path")
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d3.hsl(d.data.color).darker(0.7);
          })
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            return pieInner(d, rx + 0.5, ry + 0.5, h, ir);
          })
          .attr("class", function(d) {
            return "innerSlice slice-" + d.data.label;
          })
          .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
          })
          .on('click', clickHandler);

        slices.selectAll(".topSlice").data(_data).enter().append("path")
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d.data.color;
          })
          .style("stroke", function(d) {
            return d.data.color;
          })
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            return pieTop(d, rx, ry, ir);
          })
          .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
          })
          .attr("class", function(d) {
            return "topSlice slice-" + d.data.label;
          })
          .on('click', clickHandler);

        slices.selectAll(".outerSlice").data(_data).enter().append("path")
          .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d3.hsl(d.data.color).darker(0.7);
          })
          .attr("d", function(d) {
            return pieOuter(d, rx - .5, ry - .5, h);
          })
          .attr("class", function(d) {
            return "outerSlice slice-" + d.data.label;
          })
          .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
          })
          .on('click', clickHandler);

        slices.selectAll(".percent").data(_data).enter().append("text")
          .attr("class", function(d) {
            return "percent slice-" + d.data.label;
          })
          .attr("x", function(d) {
            return 0.6 * rx * Math.cos(0.5 * (d.startAngle + d.endAngle));
          })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
            return 0.6 * ry * Math.sin(0.5 * (d.startAngle + d.endAngle));
          })
          .text(getPercent).each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
          })
          .on('click', clickHandler);

        function clickHandler(d, i) {

          var self = d3.select(this),          
              jC = self.attr("transform");
          
          slices.selectAll('path, text').each(function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
              .attr("transform", null);
          });
          
          if (jC) return;

          var self = d3.select(this),
            pieces = ['innerSlice', 'topSlice', 'outerSlice', 'percent'],
            c = self.attr("class").split(" ")[1],
            a = (d.endAngle + d.startAngle) / 2,
            x = (ir + 15) * Math.cos(a),
            y = (ir + 15) * Math.sin(a);

          pieces.forEach(function(d) {
            slices.select("." + d + "." + c)
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + [x, y] + ")");
          });

      }
    }

    this.Donut3D = Donut3D;
    }();
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <button onClick="changeData()">Change Data</button>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Donut3D.js"></script>
  <script>
    var salesData = [{
      label: "Basic",
      color: "#3366CC"
    }, {
      label: "Plus",
      color: "#DC3912"
    }, {
      label: "Lite",
      color: "#FF9900"
    }, {
      label: "Elite",
      color: "#109618"
    }, {
      label: "Delux",
      color: "#990099"
    }];

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 700).attr("height", 300);

    svg.append("g").attr("id", "salesDonut");
    svg.append("g").attr("id", "quotesDonut");

    Donut3D.draw("salesDonut", randomData(), 150, 150, 130, 100, 30, 0.4);
    Donut3D.draw("quotesDonut", randomData(), 450, 150, 130, 100, 30, 0);

    function changeData() {
      Donut3D.transition("salesDonut", randomData(), 130, 100, 30, 0.4);
      Donut3D.transition("quotesDonut", randomData(), 130, 100, 30, 0);
    }

    function randomData() {
      return salesData.map(function(d) {
        return {
          label: d.label,
          value: 1000 * Math.random(),
          color: d.color
        };
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Mark thanks. great job .I slite modifi clickHandler ()  to close open section when another is click for open , add lices.selectAll("path")
attr("transform", null);begining of else part..

Comment: I see but,If I clicked on a open section that not close.

Answer (score -2):

Add  onclick in SVG element

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  //other code
.on('click', function(d,i){  });
```

Comment: It will be very helpfull if you add some code to expand the clicked section